# How to find the date of a day of the week from a date using PHP?

Tags: php, date

If I've got a `$date` `YYYY-mm-dd` and want to get a specific `$day` (specified by 0 (sunday) to 6 (saturday)) of the week that `YYYY-mm-dd` is in.

For example, if I got `2012-10-11` as `$date` and `5` as `$day`, I want to get `2012-10-12`, if I've got `0` as `$day`, `2012-10-14`

**EDIT:**
Most of you misunderstood it. I got some date, `$date` and want to get a day specified by 0-6 of the same week `$date` is in.

So no, I don't want the day of `$date`...

Comment: When does your week start? Monday or Sunday? I know it's Monday for most people but I'm just making sure :p

Comment: I don't think the people who answered understood the question properly. He does not want to get a number of the day by date (which would be date('w')), but he wants to specify date AND the day number and receive corresponding date from the same week as the specified date is...

Comment: The title made me think the misunderstanding too. I think it would be clearer with "as an offset" before "from"

Answer (score 170, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

```
$dayofweek = date('w', strtotime($date));
$result    = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(($day - $dayofweek).' day', strtotime($date)));
```

Answer (score 139):

You can use the date() function:

```
date('w'); // day of week
```

or

```
date('l'); // dayname
```

Example function to get the day nr.:

```
function getWeekday($date) {
    return date('w', strtotime($date));
}

echo getWeekday('2012-10-11'); // returns 4
```

Comment: I don't know why anyone would want the day of the week as a number, that seems irrelevant, everyone searching for "php day" or "php day of the week" will be wanting the day name. So +1 for your answer for the day name. Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 20):

Try

```
$date = '2012-10-11';
$day  = 1;
$days = array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday','Thursday','Friday', 'Saturday');
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($days[$day], strtotime($date)));
```

Comment: Good approach, but as you can see in Rezigned's answer, you can also use '1 day', making the $days array useless.

Comment: This seem more correct because it returns the correct date `2012-10-14` when you input `0`, @Rezigned returns `2012-10-07`

Answer (score 13):

If your date is already a `DateTime` or `DateTimeImmutable` you can use the `format` method.

```
$day_of_week = intval($date_time->format('w'));
```

The format string is identical to the one used by the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

---

To answer the intended question:

```
$date_time->modify($target_day_of_week - $day_of_week . ' days');
```

Answer (score 5):

PHP Manual said :

> w     Numeric representation of the day of the week

You can therefore construct a date with mktime, and use in it `date("w", $yourTime);`

Answer (score 5):

Just:

2012-10-11 as $date and 5 as $day

```
<?php
$day=5;
$w      = date("w", strtotime("2011-01-11")) + 1; // you must add 1 to for Sunday

echo $w;

$sunday = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2011-01-11")-strtotime("+$w day"));

$result = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($sunday)+strtotime("+$day day"));

echo $result;

?>
```

The $result = '2012-10-12' is what you want.

Answer (score 3):

I had to use a similar solution for Portuguese:

```
<?php
$scheduled_day = '2018-07-28';
$days = ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb'];
$day = date('w',strtotime($scheduled_day));
$scheduled_day = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($scheduled_day))." ($days[$day])";
// provides 28-07-2018 (Sáb)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you have to do it manually.
Get the date's current day of week, calculate the offset and add the offset to the date.

```
$current = date("w", $date)
$offset = $day - $current
$new_date = new DateTime($date)
    ->add(
        new DateInterval($offset."D")
    )->format('Y-m-d')
```

Comment: Thanks for your approach, but no, I don't have to do it manually. Have a look at Rezigned's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo date("H:i", time()); ?>
<?php echo $days[date("l", time())] . date(", d.m.Y", time()); ?>
```

Simple, this should do the trick