# How to convert created_at format to day_of_week?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to convert my **created_at** date into **day_of_week** format, and I am stuck.

Here is what I did so far :

```
$max_created_at = DB::table('inventories')->max('created_at'); 
// 2015-02-17 21:32:30

$day = DateHelper::getDay($max_created_at); 
// 17
```

With the data I have, I want to convert my `$day` into day_of_week.

Example, since today is 2/18/2015 Wednesday, it should return 3.

Comment: Whats the `DateHelper` class? That isn't part of Laravel..

Comment: That is my own helper function that I wrote. With the function `getDay()` will spit out the day only (18) - for today.

Comment: Just ask the underlaying database for it (if feasible) or use PHP's DateTime class to parse the date and then ask the instance of DateTime for the day of week. see http://docs.php.net/datetime

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP day of week](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835133/php-day-of-week)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the second line to convert to the `$day`. Since the `created_at` column is an instance of Carbon, you can just do:

```
$max_created_at->format('N');
```

Where `N` is the "ISO-8601 numeric representation of the day of the week (added in PHP 5.1.0)" according to the manual.

Edit: My bad - you probably don't have an instance of Carbon in your case. But you can do `date('N', strtotime($max_created_at))`, that'll work equally fine.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick :

```
    echo date('N', strtotime($max_created_at));
```