# MYSQL - Selecting Dates of Current Work Week

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm am writing a PHP program that will get all of the dates for the current work week (excluding Monday). My code is as follows:

```
//Get Year
$sql = "SELECT YEAR(CURDATE()) AS CurYear";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$curyear = $row['CurYear'];
//Get Week
$sql = "SELECT WEEK(CURDATE()) AS CurWeek";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$curweek = $row['CurWeek'];
//Get Date of Tuesday
$sql = "SELECT STR_TO_DATE('$curyear$curweek Tuesday', '%X%V %W') AS TueDate";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$tuedate = $row['TueDate'];
```

It works and will return the date of this Tuesday, but is there a more efficient way of doing this, and moreover doing it for the following 3 days?

Comment: why do you want to use MySQL vs doing this directly in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained here: [How to find the day of week from a date using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835133/php-day-of-week)
you can use the date command:

```
$time = time(); // present time
$day  = 3; //the day of the week we are looking for 0: sunday, 1 monday and so on
$dayofweek = date('w', $time); //current day week number
$result  = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(($day - $dayofweek).' day', $time));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have a requirement of using MySQL, but I would do this in PHP directly. Below is a sample of how you could approach it. Once the variable `$TuesTS` is set, you can figure out the next day by adding `(24*60*60)` or `86400` to it, which is the number of seconds in a day.

```
<?php
    $ts = time();
    $todayNum = date('N');
    if ( ($todayNum >= 2) && ($todayNum<=5)){
        $offset = $todayNum - 2; // number of days after Tuesday;
        $TuesTS = $ts-($offset*24*60*60);

        echo "Tuesday : ".date('Y-m-d', $TuesTS);
    }
?>
```