# Getting PHP Date format correct

Tags: php, datetime

I can't seem to get this date format correct.

I'm looking to display the current date like this:
Wednesday, May 16th

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: Check out the [PHP date documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), it covers everything you need and has lots of examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the date of a day of the week from a date using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835133/how-to-find-the-date-of-a-day-of-the-week-from-a-date-using-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo date('l,M jS');
```

php manual 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want leading zeroes (e.g. "Wednesday, May 02nd"):

```
date("l, F sS");
```

If you do not want leading zeroes (e.g. "Wednesday, May 2nd"):

```
date("l, F jS");
```