# Get weekday by date

Tags: php, date

I need to get day of week by given date, but don't know how.

It's my homework(actually question wizard testing) and I don't know where should I start

```
function weekDay($date) {
  return 'Friday'; 
}
```

I expect to get actual weekday, but always receive Friday.

Comment: Did you try to put your question on Google / StackOverflow search engine ? You will find a lot of solutions : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835133/how-to-find-the-date-of-a-day-of-the-week-from-a-date-using-php

Comment: You have this solution at: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835133/how-to-find-the-date-of-a-day-of-the-week-from-a-date-using-php?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: It's interesting but no answers in that question use createFromFormat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try like this way,

```
<?php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2018-06-21');
echo $date->format('l'); # l for full week day name
?>
```

**Ref.:** http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

**Demo:** https://eval.in/1025956