# Find next recurrence of weekly event if PHP "N" date value is given

Tags: php, time

I have a weekday value available in the PHP **date("N",$stamp)** format + a time with an starting hour of an event. I want to show the date of next week if the event has started already and the date of this week if it is in the future. The time horizon is 7 days, so if "now" has passed, the expected recurrence is in 7 days.

Example

```
now() is tuesday, 2/10/2018, 13:00
$row['weekday'] = 2 (for tuesday)
$row['time'] = 13:01
$next should be 9/10/2018
```

vs.

```
now() is tuesday, 2/10/2018, 13:00
$row['weekday'] = 2 (for tuesday)
$row['time'] = 12:00
$next should be 2/10/2018
```

Here's the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to the "N" time format:

> N ISO-8601 numeric representation of the day of the week (added in PHP 5.1.0) 1 (for Monday) through 7 (for Sunday)

I investigated quite a bit and could not find any solution to this. The only thing I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835133/how-to-find-the-date-of-a-day-of-the-week-from-a-date-using-php) which I based the following (ugly, non-working) code on.

```
$next = (intval(date("N", strtotime("now"))) !== intval($row['weekday']))
              ?
                (
                  date("d.m.Y", strtotime(
                    date("Y-m-d", strtotime("now")-strtotime("+". (date("w", strtotime("now")) +0) ." day"))
                  )+strtotime("+".$row['weekday']." day"))
                )
                :
                (
                  (
                    (strtotime("now"))
                    <
                    (( strtotime(
                      date("Y-m-d", strtotime("now")-strtotime("+". (date("w", strtotime("now")) +0) ." day"))
                    )+strtotime("+".$row['weekday']." day")+strtotime($row['time'])))
                  )
                  ?
                  (date("d.m.Y", strtotime("now")))
                  :
                  (date("d.m.Y", strtotime("now +1 week")))
                  )

              )
```

Any ideas how to tackle this?

Comment: Wow, that is really ugly code. Why not break it up into multiple conditions if it works properly?

Comment: I broke it up and gave up before because I didn't get the basic idea from the solution in the link provided. I am willing to have a complete rewrite. ;)

Comment: Could you explain a bit how $row['tuesday'] works, is there, for example, a $row['sunday'] too, and for every other day of the week?

Comment: Uh, sorry, my mistake. It should be just "weekday". I edit the code above

Answer (score 0):

You should use \DateTime and not date():

```
$eventDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date);
$today = \DateTime::createFromFormat("N", $weekDay);

$next = clone $today;

if ($today > $eventDate) {
  $next->modify("+1 week"); //$next->add(new \DateInterval("P1W"))
  //Eventually also set time
}
```

EDIT:

```
$now = new \DateTime();
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat("D", "Tue"); //W and N are not working

$dayPeriod = new \DateInterval("P1D");

//Check if in last week
if ($date->format("W") < $now->format("W")) {
    $date->add($dayPeriod);
}
//Check if in current week
if ($date->format("W") === $now->format("W")) {
    $date->add($dayPeriod);
}

echo $date->format("Y-m-d");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! The point is that $eventDate is not specified. The only thing available is a numeric value for the weekday. I only know that the event takes place on tuesdays at 12:00 - no specific date like Y-m-d