# Check Date if Saturday or Sunday

Tags: php, date

I know this question has many answers on the site, but I need a different thing.

I have an array of dates of the current month, now I want to get the days that are Saturday and Sunday.

```
$dates = array ('2019-03-01', '2019-03-02', '2019-03-03', '2019-03-04', ...);
```

I found a function that checks TODAY, but I want it to check any date with this format: YYYY-MM-DD

```
if(date('D') == 'Sat' || date('D') == 'Sun') { 
  echo "Today is Saturday or Sunday.";
} else {
  echo "Today is not Saturday or Sunday.";
}
```

Comment: What is the second argument of date? What is the usage of strtotime? Answer those two questions and you got your answer

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835133/how-to-find-the-date-of-a-day-of-the-week-from-a-date-using-php